# How to initialize a ParseObject in a cloud function?

Tags: swift, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

I want to generate a list of `ParseObject`s based on the cached data I get from `Redis`. Here's what I’m doing:

```
function parseHashtagsResponse(cachedObjects) {
    var hashtags = [];

    for (const object of cachedObjects) {
        const Hashtag = Parse.Object.extend("Hashtag");
        const hashtag = new Hashtag();

        for (var key in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                hashtag.set(key, object[key]);
            }
        }

        hashtags.push(hashtag);
    }

    return hashtags;
}
```

> `cachedObjects` is an array of dictionaries that contains the data of
> cached `ParseObject`s

This is what I do on the client to fetch the above processed data:

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "getHashtagsFunctionV3", withParameters: nil) { (response, error) in
    if error == nil, let hashtagsArray = response as? [PFObject] {
        self.hashtagsArray.append(contentsOf: hashtagsArray)
    }
}
```

When I'm receiving the response, I'm getting this:

> expression produced error: error:
> /var/folders/1h/vqb7yf6n14d52q7zdmgbx3lr0000gn/T/expr30-d84d97..swift:1:83:
> error: 'PFObject' is not a member type of 'Parse'
> Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<Swift.Array<Parse.PFObject>>(bitPattern:
> 0x11e0e08f0)!.pointee)

If I print an element of the returned array, I get this:

> <Hashtag: 0x60000331d320, objectId: hLuDPG45CI, localId: (null)> {}

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you share the code that you are using in the iOS side?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I updated my question

Comment: Could you also print out what you have in the var `object`?

Comment: I figured it out so I added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a static function of the `Parse.Object` class called `fromJSON`. What it does, is exactly what I needed... it constructs a `ParseObject` based on a JSON's data!

Here's the updated function:

```
function parseResponse(cachedObjects, className) {
    var hashtags = [];

    for (var object of cachedObjects) {
        object.className = className;
        hashtags.push(Parse.Object.fromJSON(object));
    }

    return hashtags;
}
```